# Can't play 32 bit songs with libGDX in a Runnable Jar

Tags: java, libgdx

Have a 32-bit rate song.

Your game running in Eclipse can play it alright. However, after exporting to a Runnable Jar the game crashes simply saying "Error loading MP3".

If you transform the song to 16 bit it works.

- How can I get it to work for 32 bit-rate songs?
- Why does it work in Eclipse?

The code is merely

```
Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("song.mp3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you included the native libs in your runnable jar. If you use native libs, you need to make Java load these. Eclipse does this for you.
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859902/runtime-error-in-libgdx) question. Maybe you moved your jar but not your native libraries along.

Comment: And you could post the java console output with the log messages

Comment: I will go get the logs. However the answer to the question you linked says that alternatively one should be using the GDX Setup UI - which I did.

Comment: Well this was just for getting the right native libs.